# Why does celery works with "--concurrency 1 -P solo" and not without?

Tags: django, redis, django-views, celery

When I use :

```
celery -A FAM worker -l info --concurrency 1 -P solo
```

I can run my tasks from celery.

when I use :

```
celery -A FAM worker -l info
```

It doesn't work. But I cannot understand why. I see there is a difference : "16 (prefork)" vs "1 (solo)". What is the difference ? And why does the solo works and the other does not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that **Celery does not support Windows** since version 4, and so running it on Windows can give issues. As it is with concurrency.

Based on this [article](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows/) I could solve this issue by using Eventlet.

```
pip install eventlet
```

And when starting the celery worker:

```
celery -A FAM worker -l info --concurrency 4 -P eventlet
```